# How to set the key of the object from query params in model.find

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to make the key of the object from query params in the `model.find` method.

I have already tried this:

```
moongoose.model.find({ req.query.type : req.params.tid})
```

and this:

```
let type = req.query.type
moongoose.model.find({type  : req.params.tid})
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use square brackets if you want to use the variable value as key:

```
const type = req.query.type;
mongoose.model.find({[type]: req.params.tid});
```

An example:

```js
const key = 'myKey';
const obj = { [key]: 'value' };

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should **always** use computed property names when creating an object with dynamic key names.

```
function findStuff() {
  const type = req.query.type
  const result = moongoose.model.find({type  : req.params.tid});
  return `${result}`;
}

const myObj = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b'
  [findStuff()]: 'something'
};
```